# Node/less: util.puts: Use console.log instead

Tags: node.js, less

When I run `lessc` from my terminal it's riddled with these `util.puts: Use console.log instead` warnings. How do I make them go away?

```
mbayazit:~$ lessc --help
util.puts: Use console.log instead
usage: lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]
util.puts: Use console.log instead

util.puts: Use console.log instead
If source is set to `-' (dash or hyphen-minus), input is read from stdin.
util.puts: Use console.log instead
...
```

I just installed `less` via:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install git-core
git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install

sudo npm install -g less
```

Versions:

```
mbayazit:~$ lessc --version
util.puts: Use console.log instead
lessc 1.4.2 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
mbayazit:~$ npm --version
1.3.5
mbayazit:~$ node --version
v0.11.5-pre
```

I think it may be causing other errors as well, as it won't compile my less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-pre` on the node version got me suspicious. Turns out, it's a bad build. I grabbed a stable release off the [downloads page](http://nodejs.org/download/) and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue but my node version was not tagged as pre I just had the latest.

So I did a:

```
n stable
```

Comment: worked for me! ( "n" is an npm package for installing different versions of node.js  -- kind of a bad name, but that's what it is..)