# trying to get setup with less.js

Tags: node.js, installation, less

And I followed the instructions here http://lesscss.org/#using-less-third-party-tools

It says "Once installed, you can invoke the compiler from the command-line, as such:

$ lessc styles.less"

yet I'm getting this error "bash: /usr/bin/lessc: No such file or directory".

Comment: Can you try running `/usr/local/bin/lessc` ?

Comment: lessc: no input files

Comment: when i cd into /usr/local/bin I see a lessc in blue...

Comment: Ok, so if you run `/usr/local/bin/lessc styles.less` it should compile the less file

Comment: ok I do that from the directory where style.less is located right?  It gave me util.print: Use console.log instead

Comment: Yep, from the style.less directory. The good new is that you already solved the issue, these error messages are related to your node.js version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023508/node-less-util-puts-use-console-log-instead

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where and how you installed LESS. Make sure you installed it globally with `npm install -g less`.

Depending on your operating system and shell, you may need to update your `$PATH` to include the directory in which you installed the LESS executable.

First you'll need to find out where it was installed. You can open your hidden `/usr/local` in with the shell by typing `open /usr/local`. Then try and find the directory where (and if) LESS was installed.

To do that on Mac, you can create or open up an existing `.bash-profile` document, which will be in your user folder. Add a line similar to this:

`export PATH="/usr/local/path/to/lessc:$PATH"`

This will add the directory off the LESS executable to the path that the command line uses to search for executables (like `lessc`, `mongo`, `mysql`, `sass`, etc.)

Comment: I installed it with sudo npm install -g less.  I went in /usr/local/bin and I see a "lessc".  I'm on ubuntu, do i do the same thing?

Comment: Sort of. It would be a little different. Look on Google for tutorials on how to change your $path environment variable. For now, you can probably run /usr/local/bin/lessc <command>